# Interior discontinuities of extensions of nonzero degree maps on the sphere

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I'm looking for a proof of a statement similar to the following: *let $\phi : S^2 \to S^2$ be a smooth function with $\mbox{deg}\,\phi \neq 0$. Then any extension $\Phi$ of $\phi$ to the closed ball $\overline{B^3} \subset \mathbb R^3$ has at least an **interior** discontinuity.*

To be more precise, my trouble with this statement is the fact that the discontinuity must lie in the open ball $B^3$. In particular, I was wondering why $\Phi$ cannot be discontinuous, as a function on $\overline{B^3}$, on $S^2$ (althought, restricted to $S^2$, it is smooth). Note that, when $\phi = id$, as a corollary of Lemma 5 in §2 of Milnor's *Topology from the differentiable viewpoint*, the quoted author says that the identity map $id : S^2 \to S^2$ cannot be extended to a smooth map $\overline{B^3} \to S^2$, no mention of the interior.

Comment: That is not true. Take the extension that is constant on the interior. Then discontinuities are only on the boundary. Or am I missing something?

Comment: That's exactly my point. However, this seems to be forbidden someway. The application I'm referring to is into the celebrated paper by Hardt and Lin "A remark on $H^1$ mappings", Manuscripta Math. 56, 1-10 (1986), end of proof of Theorem A.

Comment: Where do you see "... has at least an interior discontinuity." ?

Comment: Compare the last lines in the proof here: https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN365956996_0056?tify={%22pages%22:[7],%22panX%22:0.501,%22panY%22:0.843,%22view%22:%22info%22,%22zoom%22:0.34}